# Python 'return vector if vector.shape else vector.item()'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning gradient descent algorithm reading this article https://realpython.com/gradient-descent-algorithm-python/#minibatches-in-stochastic-gradient-descent and I'm stuck with one peace of Python code written by author.
There is Python code in 'Minibatches in Stochastic Gradient Descent' chapter. I will post here only part I'm stuck with.

```
def sgd(
    gradient, x, y, start, learn_rate=0.1, batch_size=1, n_iter=50,
    tolerance=1e-06, dtype="float64", random_state=None
):
...
# Initializing the values of the variables
vector = np.array(start, dtype=dtype_)
...
return vector if vector.shape else vector.item()
```

I'm not experienced with Python and cannot realize when `vector.shape` may give false in if-else block so it would return `vector.item()` instead of `vector`. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `shape` is a tuple, so if it is `()`, that will be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained by the author of the tutorial:

> This is an interesting trick [refering to `vector = np.array(start, dtype=dtype_)`]: if `start` is a Python scalar, then it’ll be
> transformed into a corresponding NumPy object (an array with one item and zero dimensions). If you pass a sequence, then it’ll become a regular NumPy array with the same number of elements.

You can see the two different cases here:

```
>>> x = np.array([2021]) # shape (1,)
>>> x if x.shape else x.item()
array([2021])
```

Whereas a scalar will be returned as a scalar using [`item`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) on the `np.array`:

```
>>> x = np.array(2021) # shape ()
>>> x if x.shape else x.item()
2021
```

Comment: Looks like I understand it now. I didn't know that we can use 'np.array(2021)' where 2021 is without brackets. Thanks. It helped.

Comment: Though `np.array(2021).item()`.  It's not obvious why they need to treat a () shape different from a (1,).